# Firebase crash logs not sent

Tags: android, firebase-crash-reporting

I've integrated Firebase Crash in my app and created a custom Uncaught Exception Handler in which I log useful app state just before sending the crash. However, in the Firebase console, the logs are not included next to the exception as expected. Why is that the case? How do I ensure that my logs always get sent?

Below's a stripped down version of the handler's uncaughtException method.

```
public void uncaughtException(Thread thread, final Throwable ex) {
    FirebaseCrash.logcat(Log.INFO, TAG, "App state");
    FirebaseCrash.report(ex);
    prior_handler.uncaughtException(thread, ex);
}
```

Comment: If Firebase Crash is installed, you won't have to call report() to send anything.  That will happen in the UncaughtExceptionHandler that Firebase adds for itself.  You simply log messages ahead of any crash or call to report(), and they should get attached to the report below the stack trace.  We haven't seen heard any complaints about missing logs.

Comment: @DougStevenson Thanks for your answer. I created my own UEHandler because in the event of uncaught exceptions, I want to include additional logging that's otherwise unnecessary. While debugging, I see that my handler (see sample above) is called and the exception shows up in the console but not the log. If I don't use a custom handler, how can I "inject" additional logs only when there's an uncaught exception?

Comment: I would expect any log to work if called prior to Firebase's UEH.  One possible problem is that your UEH might be getting registered *before* Firebase, in which case, Firebase will actually execute first before yours when a crash happens, and it won't have your additional log.  At what point are you registering yours?  Firebase's happens during a ContentProvider onCreate (which is actually very early).

Comment: I register my UEH in Application.onCreate() which is after the content providers have been created so I guess that's not the problem. By the way, for non-fatal situations where I trigger a report() call during normal execution (e.g. when a user sends a feedback form), I receive the logs. So it seems this goes wrong only when there's an uncaught exception which is sadly when I really need the additional logs :(

Comment: Update: I have two apps using the same UEH implementation in a shared library project and I just noticed that the problem only occurs in one of them. So in one app, I always get the logs but not in the other. Note: Both apps are included in the same firebase console project though I doubt that should have any effect...

Comment: Two apps in the same Firebase project, or two different projects?

Comment: Two apps in the same Firebase project. Could that be the problem?

Comment: I don't know - I've heard recent problem reports on similar configurations.  I would log your details as a bug report at https://firebase.google.com/support/contact/bugs-features/

Comment: Ok. I'll first try creating separate firebase projects for each of the apps to see if the problem is solved and then create a bug report with as much details as I can garner.

Comment: Indeed switching from two apps in one Firebase project to a single Firebase project per app solved my problem. I've created a bug request to this effect as you suggested. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Thank you, it's appreciated.

Comment: @DougStevenson I want to give my thanks to you & your team for the wonderful work you've done with this tool, it is a great addition to the scene :), one small thing though, there is a case where you have your own UEH and you don't delegate the exception to the default UEH (that being firebase UEH). if your UEH reports the crash followed by killProcess & system.exit() your crash will not be sent to firebase! maybe because it didn't get enough time to send the crash before you kill the process?

Comment: All newly added UEH should call through to the prior one.  Those that don't do this will ruin things for all the others because they never get called.  There's simply no way around this fact.  Typically there's no reason for an app to try to forcibly kill itself.  If execution is inside a UEH, then it is really just about to die.

Comment: @DougStevenson the reason why we chose not the call the prior UEH is because it causes the system to show the crash dialog "xxx app has stopped working!" and we simply want to show a customized dialog instead of that, could there be a way to bypass that?

Comment: If the app is about to crash, it's usually best to let is crash.  It could be in a bad state.  Allowing it to keep running is possibly a worse situation.  The crash dialog is controlled by Android as the final step of a crash, so you have to expect that it will happen.

Answer (score 1):

What eventually worked for me (as suggested by Doug Stevenson in one of his comments on my question above) was to create one Firebase Project per Android App.

Gladly, with this configuration, I could still separate my production crash reports/logs from the debug ones using the `applicationIdSuffix` trick mentioned [here](https://firebase.googleblog.com/2016/08/organizing-your-firebase-enabled-android-app-builds.html).